# How to construct a more efficient cooler made by cheap materials to cool a glass bottle containing hot water without pouring the water out?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, water

**details**
-limitations:it can only use five blocks of ice and the cooler must consist one container to put the glass bottle.Also,cannot interfere the water in the glass bottle such as to stir it. but other active devices installed outside the container are allowed.

Comment: What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: what size blocks?

Answer (score 1):

You do not give sizes to be cooled. A bottle in a bucket I would add crushed ice, salt and water around it. Water for convection cooling of glass surface, [salt to force](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5748/why-does-ice-water-get-colder-when-salt-is-added) the ice to melt so the water gets cold faster. Also stirring would increase the rate of cooling.